# Type values for SSRS parameter with default value

Tags: reporting-services, types, parameters

I have a multi value parameter.

I want to set it up so that

1. It is defaulted to all values in the data set. (can be achieved easily). 
   but at the same time
2. I want the user to be able to ignore the defaulted values and ***TYPE*** his values.

Right now I can set it up so that the user can check multiple values. If I want the user to be able to type, because the parameter is already defaulted to a long list, he has to erase every thing in order to be able to type in.

Is there any way it can be achieved? Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this can be done. Use two parameters.

1. Your current parameter as it works now.
2. A text parameter.

If the text parameter IS NULL (NOTHING), use the 1st parameter. Otherwise use the second parameter.

Your SQL would look something like:

```
WHERE (FIELD IN (@Param1) and @Param2 IS NULL) 
   OR (FIELD = @Param2 and @Param2 IS NOT NULL)
```

If the users can type in multiple values, use CHARINDEX instead:

```
WHERE (FIELD IN (@Param1) and @Param2 IS NULL) 
   OR (CHARINDEX(FIELD, @Param2) > 0)
```

Comment: You are correct.  I also thought of the two parameter approach but got hung up on not being able to make the multi-select nullable instead of just ignoring it if there was text in the free-text parameter so discounted it.  This still doesn't mean that you can have everything in the one parameter though as the OP probably originally envisaged.

Comment: @Jonnus - I went with the "any way it can be achieved" part.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No.  A Multi-select parameter is controlled by the dropdown and checkboxes therein.  It is not possible in SSRS 2008/2010 to make this free text also.

**Update**

[Hannover Fist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33922774/2311633) does have a workaround however using more than one parameter